# One-Time pad XOR cipher

Tags: python, encryption, hex

So below has a number of english sentences which are encrypted using the same one-time pad key. I'm trying to decrypt it using xor cipher so I have started of with the following.

```
Guessing the first character as an "A"
7B (hex) XOR 41(hex of A) = 3A (hex) 
3A XOR with 7B, 77, 6A, 6E, 6D, 7D
I get       A , M,  P , T  , W  , G
```

I wanted to know if there was a quicker way to doing this as it seems very time consuming to guess the first character and do a lot of trial and error. Tried to write a python code for it but wasn't sure how to start. I hope this question made sense.

7B53D5EE7646755E999A2AFFDFCB353FA05077003BEB3FCCCB96
7B44DBF7760366108ADB2CB0D6D9323FA34C660C77FD22C7CB96
7757C2F925047B5189C97EF7CBD9337BE64D60093BF525CECA96
6A42DBEE6015344798C83BB0CDD0286FB65A614D6FF332C3D696
6E53D0EE60157051849A33FFCCD62871A11F6C1E3BFA3FCCCA96
6D5ED1F925076655DDD431E49ECB297EB44F250875F323C5C796
7D5FD7F46C097A518FC37EF1CACC207CAD1F76197AEE22C7CB96

Answer (score 0):

If you directly Xor two characters(in hex) there is no need to all of that operations.

```
for i in range(len(allplain)):
   k = chr (key[i])
   p = chr (allplain[i])
   c = chr ((ord(p)) ^ (ord(k)))
   f2.write(c)
```

this is a complete implementation of One-Time Pad encryption in Python.
I hope it helps ones who search for a solution in python and you can easily convert it to Java.

[One-Time Pad Encryption](https://shooreshsufiye.blogspot.se/2017/11/one-time-pad-encryption-in-python.html)

Answer (score 0):

In order to decode the messages, the computer needs to have some idea whether or not it has guessed the key correctly or not. We know the messages are in English, so we have to make the computer understand that somehow.

For this purpose, you can use a statistical model that tells the computer how likely a sequence of bytes is to be English. Perhaps the most basic kind of statistical model is a simple letter frequency table. (This works pretty well for your particular cipher texts.)

The way the English is encoded into bytes also matters. We can guess that the text uses ASCII, though. So, we want a that tells us how likely each byte value is to occur in English text encoded in ASCII.

You may be able to find such tables online, but generally the source of such information comes from analyzing a large amount of data (a "[corpus](https://github.com/niderhoff/nlp-datasets)"). The better the data matches (in terms of style, word-choice, spelling, capitalization, use of spacing, etc. -- although only things that are detected in the model will matter) the text you are trying to decode, the better the computer decoding will tend to do.

With a model in hand, we can use Bayesian estimation to determine the most likely key. The math here might sound a bit scary, but for the letter frequency case it turns out pretty simple. Formally, we assume a uniform prior on all the possible keys, and assume that the plaintexts are independently chosen from the distribution given by the model. Then the likelihood of a key is proportional to the (prior) likelihood of the set of plaintexts it entails which is easily calculated from the model. For letter frequency, this is made easier since each letter is independent and we can make a guess for each byte of the key separately.

(If you use a model where the text can't be broken into small independent chunks, you probably can't consider every key, as there will be far too many, but you can use a smarter search algorithm e.g. Dijkstra's or A* to avoid considering every key by avoiding unlikely prefixes.)

For this example, I've used the first hundred files from [The Blog Authorship Corpus](http://u.cs.biu.ac.il/%7Ekoppel/BlogCorpus.htm) (chosen fairly arbitrarily). (Note that this corpus is XML, so I'm not technically parsing it correctly, but the amount of metadata and syntax overhead is small enough that I don't think it matters much for this simple example.)

(Disclaimer: I don't write much Python.)

```
import os
import glob

# Build language model by digesting corpus

frequency = [0 for i in xrange(0, 256)]

filecount = 0
for filename in glob.iglob(os.path.join('Corpus', '*')):
    filecount += 1
    if filecount > 100: break
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        for c in f.read():
            frequency[ord(c)] += 1

sum = 0
for count in frequency: sum += count
frequency = [(1.0 * count) / sum for count in frequency]

# Hard-coded message data

messages = [
    b"\x7B\x53\xD5\xEE\x76\x46\x75\x5E\x99\x9A\x2A\xFF\xDF\xCB\x35\x3F\xA0\x50\x77\x00\x3B\xEB\x3F\xCC\xCB\x96",
    b"\x7B\x44\xDB\xF7\x76\x03\x66\x10\x8A\xDB\x2C\xB0\xD6\xD9\x32\x3F\xA3\x4C\x66\x0C\x77\xFD\x22\xC7\xCB\x96",
    b"\x77\x57\xC2\xF9\x25\x04\x7B\x51\x89\xC9\x7E\xF7\xCB\xD9\x33\x7B\xE6\x4D\x60\x09\x3B\xF5\x25\xCE\xCA\x96",
    b"\x6A\x42\xDB\xEE\x60\x15\x34\x47\x98\xC8\x3B\xB0\xCD\xD0\x28\x6F\xB6\x5A\x61\x4D\x6F\xF3\x32\xC3\xD6\x96",
    b"\x6E\x53\xD0\xEE\x60\x15\x70\x51\x84\x9A\x33\xFF\xCC\xD6\x28\x71\xA1\x1F\x6C\x1E\x3B\xFA\x3F\xCC\xCA\x96",
    b"\x6D\x5E\xD1\xF9\x25\x07\x66\x55\xDD\xD4\x31\xE4\x9E\xCB\x29\x7E\xB4\x4F\x25\x08\x75\xF3\x23\xC5\xC7\x96",
    b"\x7D\x5F\xD7\xF4\x6C\x09\x7A\x51\x8F\xC3\x7E\xF1\xCA\xCC\x20\x7C\xAD\x1F\x76\x19\x7A\xEE\x22\xC7\xCB\x96",
]    

length = len(max(messages, key=lambda message: len(message)))

# Guess the key
key = []
for i in xrange(0, length):
    best_keybyte = 0
    best_keybyte_p = 0.0
    for keybyte in xrange(0, 256):
        # Calculate the prior probability of the plaintext for this key byte
        p = 1.0
        for message in messages:
            if i < len(message):
                messagebyte = ord(message[i])
                plaintext = chr(messagebyte ^ keybyte)
                p *= frequency[ord(plaintext)]
        if p > best_keybyte_p:
            best_keybyte = keybyte
            best_keybyte_p = p
    key.append(best_keybyte)

# Decode the messages based on the guess
for message in messages:
    plaintext = ""
    for i in xrange(0, len(message)):
        plaintext += chr(ord(message[i]) ^ key[i])
    print(plaintext)
```

This gives:

```
eears and toast form wtni 
erokser war has escalaiei 
iave boats guard red inlh 
ttores were shipped toyat 
pedresday morning is ftnh 
shee are not sharp enohge 
cichionary attack stariei
```

(Note that each line has a trailing space.)

Clearly this is not perfect, but it is close enough that you can probably (using your superior knowledge of English) fix the errors pretty easily by hand.

Using a superior model of English could help the computer fix such problems automatically. For example, the letter frequency model doesn't know that messages are likely to start with a capital letter. A common refinement would be to consider the frequency of pairs of letters.

Answer (score -1):

Can you tell me a bit more about it? It sounds to me like to are just trying to use the same key bit for each character in the encrypted message, which would only work if the message was encrypted with all the characters using the same key bit. In that case, you could just do a frequency analysis of the hex characters to see which ones appear most often, and figure it out that way?

Comment: I'm going with the column by column approach i guess. So first row I will do 7b,7b,77,6a,6e,6d,7d. Second row  I will do 53,44,57,42,53,5e,5f etc if that made sense

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. It should be a comment.

Comment: @James, I'm aware. However, due to low reputation I wasn't allowed to comment. Thanks for the downvote.